# ASP.NET Core - controller will not return a view

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a problem with my controller - it doesn't return a view. I am sending some data to the same controller, creating a new object with this data and I would like to send this object to the Create view but for some kind of reason I am staying on the same page.

- View name: `Create.cshtml`
- Controller name: `ReservationController`

Here is my controller action:

```
public IActionResult Create(int selectedTime, string selectedDate, int selectedRoomId)
{
    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse($"{selectedTime}:00:00");
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(selectedDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime combine = date + time;

    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    reservation.RoomId = selectedRoomId;
    reservation.ReservationTime = combine;

    return View(reservation);
}
```

And my view:

```
@model Escape.Models.Reservation

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

<h2>My create reservation view</h2>
```

This is the original view I am coming from:

```
@using Escape.Controllers
@model Escape.Models.Room

@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
 }


<h4 class="title">Booking for room: @Model.Name</h4>
<div>
   <p>@Model.Description</p>
   <a class="btn btn-link" asp-action="Index">Back to all rooms</a>
   <hr />
</div>

<div>
   <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="datepicker" 
    onchange="onDateChange(@Model.Id)" />
</div>

<div>
   <div id="displayTimes"></div>
   <a id="btn-create" class="btn btn-sm"></a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
  <script>
    var dateToday = new Date();
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday
        });
    });
  </script>
}
```

Ajax function on my btn-create:

```
function onButtonClick(val, date, room) {
    var btnBack = document.getElementById("btn-create");
    btnBack.innerHTML = "Create reservation";
    $(btnBack).addClass('btn-outline-primary');

    btnBack.addEventListener("click",
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: { selectedTime: val, selectedDate: date, selectedRoomId: room },
                url: "/Reservation/Create",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: When you say you stay on the same page, what is the view from which you are calling this method?

Comment: We need a fully reproducible example.  We need to see the original view and the link or form you are using to navigate to the other view etc.

Comment: I edited my question - added original view.

Comment: Before returning the view what do you see setting breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If the link `<a id="btn-create" class="btn btn-sm"></a>` is supposed to make a call to the **`Create`** method of the `ReservationController`, then it is incomplete, and this is what you would need to change it to:

```
<a asp-controller="Reservation"
   asp-action="Create"
   id="btn-create" class="btn btn-sm">Create</a>
```

---

*Update:*

Your click handler does seem to send a request to the Controller, but nothing happens *after* that request, and the response (which contains the HTML from the View) is discarded.

Since you want to show the HTML, maybe you shouldn't even be using AJAX, and use my original answer above instead.

If for some reason you need the AJAX, then you need to create a `success` handler that displays the HTML:

```
btnBack.addEventListener("click",
    function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { selectedTime: val, selectedDate: date, selectedRoomId: room },
            url: "/Reservation/Create",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // ... put processing here 
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have javascript function on this button where I send data by Ajax and it's url is pointing at action Create in my Reservation controller. I added this function to my question.